# Can somebody please explain this code to me?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5):
    while True:
        count += len(phrase)
        break
    print("Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count))
```

I'm confused at `count += len(phrase)`

I feel count `+= len(phrase)` => `count = count + len(phrase)`

When count `+= 1` then it's understandable that it's incrementing by 1 with every next iteration but here it's iterating the whole length so I couldn't get the logic behind it. I request if anyone can explain me line by line what is actually happening in this code. Thanks!

Comment: The `while True` and `break` are just obfuscation. The result is the same if they are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5): #iterate 5 times
    while True:
        #count = count + len(phrase)
        count += len(phrase)  # add the length of phrase to current value of count.
        break                 # break out of while loop, while loop 
                              # runs only once for each iteration
    #print the value of current count
    print("Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count))
```

So, in short the program added the length of `phrase` to `count` 5 times.

**output:**

```
Iteration 0; count is: 12   # 0+12
Iteration 1; count is: 24   # 12+12
Iteration 2; count is: 36   # 24+12
Iteration 3; count is: 48   # 36+12
Iteration 4; count is: 60   # 48+12
```

The above program is roughly equivalent to :

```
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5):
    count = count + len(phrase)
    print("Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count))
```

Comment: Which is equivalent to `count = 5 * len("hello, world")`...

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary thanks for your  detailed explanation!

Comment: @Thijs Van Thank you too !

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition about `+=` is correct; the `+=` operator means in-place addition and for immutable value types such as `int` is *exactly* the same thing as `count = count + len(phrase)`.

The outer `for` loop is run through 5 times; so `count` is in the end set to 5 times the length of `phrase`.

You can remove the `while True:` loop altogether. It starts a loop that iterates just *once*; the `break` ends that loop *during the first iteration*.

Nowhere in this code is anything iterating over the full length of the `phrase` value. Only it's length (12) is queried and added to `count`, so the end value is 5 times 12 equals 60.